# How do I eliminate libs in Maven ear build?

Tags: eclipse, maven, ear

I have 3 projects. The first one reads a database and creates all of the class files for my ejbs. The second one is my ejbs. The third one is my .ear project that is supposed to package the ejb .jar from the second project into an .ear.

Project 1 works fine and is run as a java app.

Project 2 works fine, and has several maven run configurations, one to create the client jars, one to deploy those client jars to Nexus, and one to create the ejb .jar that will be packaged in the .ear that is deployed to the server.

Project 3 is a problem though. In the past I've just exported the .ear in eclipse, and this has worked just fine. Now I am trying to get it to work with Maven. I've mostly got it working, but it keeps including a bunch of library files, and it is copying the wrong file.

Here is the pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb</groupId>
<artifactId>kds-ejb-ear</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.kable.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>kable-super-pom</artifactId>
    <version>[0.1,1.0)</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>kds-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>kdsejbEar</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kds-ejb</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>kdsSession.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                </modules>
                <displayName>kdsejbEar</displayName>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The second project has a run configuration that creates the ejb .jar and calls it kdsSession.jar

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <jarName>kdsSession</jarName>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.apache.commons.lang3</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I want to use that jar in my .ear. The following is output from the ear project.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb:kds-ejb-ear:ear:1.0.0
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building kds-ejb-ear 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ kds-ejb-ear ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\bray\eclipse-workspaces\kds-ejb\kdsejbEar\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.10:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ kds-ejb-ear ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ kds-ejb-ear ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\bray\eclipse-workspaces\kds-ejb\kdsejbEar\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.10:ear (default-ear) @ kds-ejb-ear ---
[INFO] Copying artifact [ejb:com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb:kds-ejb:1.1.0-20181024.164321-158] to [kdsSession.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:1.0.2.Final] to [jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-ext-api:2.2.0.Final] to [jboss-ejb3-ext-api-2.2.0.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.1.13.Final] to [hibernate-envers-5.1.13.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final] to [jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.13.Final] to [hibernate-core-5.1.13.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final] to [hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA] to [javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:antlr:antlr:2.7.7] to [antlr-2.7.7.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1] to [geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.jboss:jandex:2.0.3.Final] to [jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1] to [dom4j-1.6.1.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final] to [hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8] to [slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.13.Final] to [hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.13.Final.jar]
[INFO] Copying artifact [jar:org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5] to [commons-lang3-3.5.jar]
[INFO] Copy ear sources to C:\Users\bray\eclipse-workspaces\kds-ejb\kdsejbEar\target\kdsejbEar
[INFO] Could not find manifest file: C:\Users\bray\eclipse-workspaces\kds-ejb\kdsejbEar\target\kdsejbEar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF - Generating one
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\bray\eclipse-workspaces\kds-ejb\kdsejbEar\target\kdsejbEar.ear
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-25T14:09:10-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/332M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, it is copying some library files for some reason. I do not want those. It is also not getting the preexisting kdsSession.jar, but rather creating a new one.

How do I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ear project run `mvn dependency:tree`

Have a look at it and try to figure out where the unwanted jars come from.

Maybe you have the dependencies declared in your `kds-ejb` project.
If that is the case, set the scope to provided.

Further informations on scopes can be found at [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)